# Saving the page without Name

Tags: visualforce

I am writting a VF for opportunity, that becomes the standard page for creating a new Opportunity. It should have all required Opportunity fields (account, close date, etc.) EXCEPT name.

I have written the page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.AccountId}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.StageName}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Now while saving the page, it is throwing the error

So my question is, in this scenarion can we save the page without the opportunity name??

> Opportunity Name: Required fields are missing: [Opportunity Name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a trigger on Opportunity (event before insert) and set the name there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't save an opportunity without a name. What you could do is add a hidden input field on the page that you use to set a default value for the opportunity but having the same name for all opportunities is generally not handy.